# Is there place to store some data where no-one can access it?

Tags: java, android

I need to save some URL that could change later in my app. I want that no-one can see them and find these URLs.

I tried `SharedPrefences` and database but they are easily accessible by any one who has a rooted phone.

Is there anyway to encode this data and save them in `SharedPrefences` so that I can decrypt it in the app?

Answer (score 2):

[encrypted-userprefs](https://github.com/sveinungkb/encrypted-userprefs) is a good library that allows you to encrypt the saved preferences. However, keep in mind that through reverse engineering, it might still be possible to retrieve the encryption keys from your APK and since you're using a URL, your app is likely to request it at some point where a network tool such as WireShark can observe it.

Comment: If you're really worried about security, I would recommend against this. Anyone with access to the bytecode could pretty easily find out what `secureKey` is, at which point they can easily decrypt the SharedPreferences file.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it difficult, but you can't make it impossible.

Think about it: you want the information to be accessible to your app (you didn't say that, but I'm assuming it), but inaccessible to everyone else. That means your app has to have more information than anyone else, even a human who has root access to the phone.

Anyone who has that level of access to your phone has access to the app's bytecode. They can use this to see what your app does, down to the finest detail. In other words, what information does your app have that a human can't gain access to? *None.* Anything your app can do, a determined human with root access can also do.

Sensitive information should always be stored server-side. Even then, anyone with root access to your server can get at that information (for the same reasons as above); but the idea is that everyone and their mother can download the app, but people you trust (employees, etc) can get at the server.